# Fixing the URl so there is no spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that has its location generated dynamically via jquery:

```
<a id="final_location" 
   href="/pre_config/step4" 
   class="proceed-btn right">Proceed To Next Step &gt;&gt;&gt;</a>
```

```
    $('#final_location').click(function() {
        location.href = this.href + '/' + escape($('#type_of_station').html()) + 
            '/' + escape($('.number_changer').attr("id").slice(-1));
        return false;
    });
```

this works great but the problem comes into play when the html in type_of_station is two words... I get this url:

```
pre_config/step4/Pizza Delivery/2
```

Is there a way to make the url only give me the first word like this:

```
pre_config/step4/Pizza/2
```

maybe this can be changed to only return the first word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
encodeURIComponent($('#type_of_station').text().match(/^\S*/)[0])
```

instead of `escape($('#type_of_station').html())` to get the first word (separated by space).

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the first word in the phrase:

```
var type = $('#type_of_station').html();
var i = type.indexOf(' ');
if (i != -1) type = type.substr(0, i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
var name = "Pizza Delivery";
var pieces = name.split(" ");

alert(pieces[0]); // Pizza
```

Or just do:

```
var name = "Pizza Delivery";
name = name.replace(/\s/g, "-", name); // feel free to change the - delimiter

alert(name); // Pizza-Delivery
```